# Cannot get Spring Boot's buildInfo() to work when Artifactory Gradle plugin is used

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, artifactory

- Gradle: 2.13
- Boot: 1.3.5
- Artifactory Gradle Plugin (org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle): 4.5.0

This project has been building for for some time. However, now I'm trying to get some additional build information to display via the /info endpoint so, per [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-build-info), I added:

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

Now there seems to be some sort of conflict with the Artifactory Gradle plugin:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.DoubleDelegateWrapper(org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.ArtifactoryClientConfiguration$BuildInfoHandler)
    at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.ArtifactoryPluginConvention.buildInfo(ArtifactoryPluginConvention.groovy:64)
    at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.ArtifactoryPluginConvention.invokeMethod(ArtifactoryPluginConvention.groovy)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$GroovyObjectAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:279)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:212)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:150)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
    at build_do1tse3u3lgd8dbntr9ir9lk6$_run_closure5.doCall(/Users/jbisotti/sandbox/fusion/fusion-eureka-service/build.gradle:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage$ExtensionHolder.configure(ExtensionsStorage.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage.configureExtension(ExtensionsStorage.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:207)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:150)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
    at build_do1tse3u3lgd8dbntr9ir9lk6.run(/Users/jbisotti/sandbox/fusion/fusion-eureka-service/build.gradle:75)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 50 more
```

I'm not sure which of the three suspects are at fault, nor how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out buildInfo() was not added until Spring Boot 1.4.0. D'oh!